# Getter and setter for a k-d nested list-of-lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to build accessors for a kd nested list-of-lists such as this 4D example (of shape \$ 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \$):

```
kd_lol = [
  [
    [
      [0,1],
      [2,3]
    ],
    [
      [4,5],
      [6,7]
    ]
  ], 
  [
    [
      [8,9],
      [10,11]
    ],
    [
      [12,13],
      [14,15]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I use a list of values to access and modify elements in this nested list-of-lists.

In the above example, you can access something using `[i,j,k,l]` where \$ 0 \le i,j,k,l < 2 \$.

I'd like to build a fast, efficient getter in idiomatic Python of the form:

```
def get(grid, list_of_indices)
def put(grid, list_of_indices, value)
```

My current implementation is as follows:

```
def get(grid, list_of_indices):
  cur_grid = grid
  for index in list_of_indices:
          cur_grid = cur_grid[index]
  assert(type(cur_grid) != type([])) # not a list
  return cur_grid
```

and

```
def put(grid, list_of_indices, value):
  cur_grid = grid
  for index in list_of_indices[:-1]:
    cur_grid = cur_grid[index]
  assert(type(cur_grid) == type([]))    # must be a 1D list
  assert(type(cur_grid[0]) != type([])) # must be a 1D list
  cur_grid[list_of_indices[-1]] = value
```

Any critique/suggestions to tidy up or reduce the amount of code above is welcome.

[Here](https://repl.it/MmvD)'s a repl that you can play with.

Comment: Would you kindly change 'list-of-lists' to 'matrix', since that's the formal definition?

Comment: @Coal_, [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) a matrix typically refers to a 2D structure only.  [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202269/correct-name-for-multi-dimensional-array-matrix-tensor) doesn't seem certain either. I'll leave this edit to the wisdom of CRSE.

Answer (score 3):

Some very nice code, overall. There's some minor points I think could be improved, but your general implementation is good.

### Nitpicks

I'd like to point out some small 'issues' regarding best-practice and code style:

- [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends using 4 spaces for indentation. They're not too fond of tabs, but most editors will replace tabs with  spaces automatically.
- Using `assert` is great for catching bugs, but it'd better to `raise` an exception instead when releasing your code. This allows us to specify a specific exception type (like `ValueError` or `TypeError`) and provides some additional stack trace information.
- It's important to use good names for objects. You're almost there, but a name like `cur_grid` may as well just be called `current_grid`, for clarity.
- Instead of manually comparing `type`, we can use `isinstance` which allows something like this: `assert not isinstance(curr_grid, list)`.

### Implementation

The code as is works just fine if you need to modify a matrix, but wouldn't it be useful to turn it into a separate object altogether? We can do this by creating a custom `class`:

```
import collections


class Matrix(collections.UserList):
    """A Matrix represents a collection of nested list objects.
    Methods:
    get -- Get a value from the matrix.
    put -- Put a value into the matrix.
    """
    def __init__(self, data):
        """Constructor.

        :param list data: a matrix (multi-dimensional list).
        :return: None
        """
        super(Matrix, self).__init__(data)

    def get(self, indices):
        """Get a value from the matrix.

        :param iterable indices: iterable containing indices.
                                 the last index must point to an object
                                 that is not a list.
        :return: matrix at indices[-1]
        :raises TypeError: if the last index points to a list
        """
        grid = self.data
        # As assigned by UserList
        for index in indices:
            grid = grid[index]
        if isinstance(grid, list):
            raise TypeError("last element is not 1-dimensional")
        return grid

    def put(self, indices, value):
        """Put value at matrix[indices].

        :param iterable indices: iterable containing indices.
                                 the last index must point to a list.
        :return: None
        :raises TypeError: if the last element is not a list
        :raises TypeError: if the last element contains a list
        """
        grid = self.data
        for index in indices[:-1]:
            grid = grid[index]
        if not isinstance(grid, list):
            error = "expected 'list' node, but got '{}'".format(type(grid))
            raise TypeError(error)
        if isinstance(grid[0], list):
            raise TypeError("last element is not 1-dimensional")
        grid[indices[-1]] = value
```

Note: the class as implemented must be initialized with a matrix and breaks if an empty iterable is passed for `data`.